# Web sign-in with OpenID Connect in Azure Active Directory B2C gives id_token instead of access_token

Tags: c#, typescript, azure, openid, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following this guide from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect

Sending the first authentication request gives me the expected `code` and `id_token` in response.

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6
&response_type=code+id_token
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faadb2cplayground.azurewebsites.net%2F
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid%20offline_access
&state=arbitrary_data_you_can_receive_in_the_response
&nonce=12345
```

.ts file, Microsoft example values but added for clarity.

```
export const login = async () => {
    // window.location.origin is safe due to specified Redirect URIs for ADB2C
    window.location.href = "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?"
        + "client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6"
        + "&nonce=anyRandomValue"
        + "&redirect_uri=" + window.location.origin + "/signin-oidc"
        + "&scope=openid%20offline_access"
        + "&response_type=code+id_token";
}
```

However the get a token request:

```
POST {tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: {tenant}.b2clogin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6&scope=90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6 offline_access&code=AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGBCmLdgfSTLEMPGYuNHSUYBrq...&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

Should return this according to the example:

```
{
    "not_before": "1442340812",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1Q...",
    "scope": "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6 offline_access",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "refresh_token": "AAQfQmvuDy8WtUv-sd0TBwWVQs1rC-Lfxa_NDkLqpg50Cxp5Dxj0VPF1mx2Z...",
}
```

What I get is instead a new `id_token`:

```
{
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1602766192,
    "id_token_expires_in": 3600,
    "profile_info": "eyJ2ZXIiOiIxL...",
    "scope": "offline_access openid",
    "refresh_token": "eyJraWQiOiJjc...",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 1209600
}
```

C#:

```
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

var kvpList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6 offline_access"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", {code}));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", HttpContext.Request.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Request.Host + "/signin-oidc"));
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "{mySecret}"));

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/token")
{ Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(kvpList) };

using var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);

var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think your `scope` needs to contain a scope value. If you go to Expose an API in the app registration, you can define a scope there. Then you can use its id when requesting tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask for "openid offline_access", then you only ask for the id-token and a refresh token. To get an access token, you need ask for a scope that is associated with the resource/API you want access to.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why Microsoft has an example with that scope and then a successful token response with `access_token`...

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed scope that was the error. Get it from your Azure AD B2C App registrations or Applications (Legacy).

[image]

My example is read.

https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6/read

TS:

```
"&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6/read"
```

C#:

```
kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid offline_access https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6/read"));
```

After this everything worked.